# Why doesn't Lord Shiva hate Asuras?

Tags: shiva, puranas, asuras

Lord Shiva had given many boons to many Asuras although the Asuras are not good. Why doesn't Lord Shiva hate the Asuras?

Comment: I don't think Brahma or even Vishnu hates Asuras. Even Vishnu had Asura devotee .

Comment: Lord Shiva doesn't hate or love Devas or Asuras. He is neutral. But Lord Vishnu's main Dharma (duty) is to preserve and establish *Dharma*.. So, He uses his Maya and upholds Dharma. However, Shiva doesn't use Maya like Vishnu and Shiva can be understood easily unlike Vishnu. To understand Vishnu, you need to understand His Maya and leela. While Samudra Mathanan, Vishnu took side of Devas and Shiva being neutral drank *Halahal*

Comment: Do parents hate their children who are bad ?Do they differentiate between good and bad offsprings?Then how can Parameswara hate one of his children?Parameswara & Parameswari are the parents of all beings that exist .Then how can they hate ?That is out of question.bro.

Comment: No god hates anyone. Asuras also are his creation.

Answer (score 6):

If someone does penance,whoever he might be, whether a Deva ,asura,pisaca or a manava, he deservedly earned his rights to boons.So, the God is bound to give him boons within the permissible limits,and it does not matter at all  for what purpose the devotee is asking for that boon or what he does with that boon in future.

So,in short,it will be against Vidhi ke Bidhan(the divine system of laws) for any God to deny a devotee his boons once he had done sufficient penance.

Asuras not only do penance to Lord Shiva but, also (as seen on numerous occasions), to Lord Brahma as well.

Lord Vishnu ,who being the preserver of Dharma, is apparently and naturally somewhat inimical towards the Asuras who are always in opposition to the beneficial forces of nature called the Gods.

That is the main reason why you seldom find an Asura praying to Lord Vishnu and asking for boons.But there are a few examples of that too.And once the asura does sufficient penance even Lord Vishnu can't deny him a boon.